# Running a .NET Web Server on AWS

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services

I am not sure the steps I have taken are ok so I will write what I've done:
1) Created a new Windows Server 2012.
2) Moved my .NET web project files into inetpub\wwwroot.
3) With server manager -> added Web Server (IIS) role
4) On IIS Manager added my website with physical path to the project Dir.
5) Set up index.html as my Default Document.

After that I entered my instances public DNS, and got to index.html, but all the API calls from JS, get 500 (Internal server error).

I'm not sure what the problem is, can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Start by checking the "Windows Error Log" on that server. The 500 status code means something unexpected happened on the server during the request and it likely means that something is not configured/working correctly on your server.

Comment: Can you RDP to the server and hit the site via localhost/YourSiteNameHere ?? This should give you workable error messages not exposed when hitting it from the public facing side.

Comment: You must include the asp.net and the .net framework you are using. For the application you must check the application pool to match your framework version and use this application pool in your app or web site.

Dont use the html page to test, use a .net page or view to test if the .net engine is in place

Comment: @mjw I've used rdp to connect to the instance, used localhost/MySiteName, I got the right html file back, but the API call got error 500, is there anyway to debug it?

Comment: Start with the logs as suggested. If you have another simple .aspx page you can use to test, start with that. It will indicate any configuration issues right away.